# Can't manage to install teleop_base package

Tags: ros, teleop-base, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
I'm new to ROS and I recently finished the documentation's tutorial. My next step would be to try some ROS functionalities in a simulator before putting them to practice with a real robot.
I tried to follow the 'stage' tutorial ([here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot)), but I can't get past the step after 'rosmake stage'. I don't know how to 'install' the teleop_base package. I get that with svn you check the version and in the link there are the files, but... is there a simple command to do this or do I download everything and include its path in $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Here's what pops up when I try 'rosmake teleop_base'

> '[ rosmake ] Packages requested are:
> ['teleop_base']
> [ rosmake ] Logging to
> directory/home/alonsoj1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110928-154556
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args
> ['teleop_base'] to: []
> [ rosmake ] WARNING: The following
> args could not be parsed as stacks or
> packages: ['teleop_base']
> [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could
> be parsed into valid package or stack
> names.

What does this mean? I just would like to be able to control the robot with the keyboard.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11344/can%27t-manage-to-install-teleop_base-package/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to include the new directory in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. I do this by adding the following to my .bashrc:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/myuser/mypackagesdirectory:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

or

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/myuser/mypackagesdirectory:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks
```

(Don't forget to source your .bashrc after adding this line)

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally could (I changed the stack directory again, so I had to refresh the bashrc).
Once I did that I came up with a problem compiling teleop_base (it needed joy), so I went [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy) and installed it. It still got some 'warnings', but now it teleop_base_keyboard runs finally :).

It doesn't respond for now, but I'm sure I'll figure it out somehow. (EDIT: fixed, the problem I had was that when I opened teleop_base_keyboard I pressed a keystroke that wasn't part of the ones that you're supposed to press to move the robots, so the program stops and wouldn't respond)

Thanks A LOT :)!!! (I was completely lost in the woods there for a while)

PS: Sorry for that incomplete answer, I had a problem before with the session and I realized half through writing the answer what was wrong. Everything is fixed now!!! Again, thanks!

---

Originally posted by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) with karma: 385 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1